# PHP - MySQL Why is this query never returning false?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm busy with an PHP/MySQL login system, just for fun.
I made this function:

```
function login($username, $password) {
     $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);
     $password = md5($password);

     return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
```

But for some reason it always returns the user_id, never false, even when the login credentials are wrong!

Comment: Why are you still using the `mysql_` library - it is deprecated

Comment: Also, the `md5hash()` should not be used with passwords...

Comment: @EdHeal As I said, I'm making this for fun, I don't have to protect it against SQL injections, I don't have to use the newest functions. It's just for fun

Comment: @arkascha same story for you ;)

Comment: @bramhaag - i guess this is a learning exercise so why not get into the habit of doing things correctly?

Comment: @EdHeal Point taken.I will convert all the mysql code into mysqli, but that will probably still not solve my issue

Comment: i think it will always return true, how mane user_id and username you got in your database, and which one it return.

Comment: please don't even get in the habit of doing things this way "for fun"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function login($username, $password) {
     //$user_id = user_id_from_username($username); // remove this line down to the if statement
     $password = md5($password);

     $query = mysql_query("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");

     // Check if the query was a success
     if($query) {
        // Check if there is a user with the matching data
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
           $user_id = user_id_from_username($username); // To here. So now this is only called when the credentials are correct
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;     
        }
     }
  }
```

but you should really start useing `mysqli_*` or `PDO`, `mysql_*` is deprecated and removed as of PHP7. Also don't trust `md5()` as it is easily cracked. use something like `hash('sha512', md5($password));`

Try the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `active` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
$return = mysql_result($result, 0); // Should be 0 or 1, I don't know this for sure. You need to try it out

// If query is a success
if($result) {
    if ($return > 0 && $return < 3) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Comment: @bramhaag Oh wait, I just noticed that you are checking against the `$username` so I will fix that in the answer.

Comment: It is just doing the same thing :( Cannot tag you for a reason :'(

Comment: @bramhaag Have tried to put some echos in the code to check where it fails?

Comment: @bramhaag and what is the `$result` in the `mysql_result()` refurring to?

Comment: Thanks! But for some reason the login part still doesn't work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62875/discussion-between-superdj-and-bramhaag).